# Creating clickable URLs in a contenteditable element

Tags: html, hyperlink, contenteditable

I have to create an area on my HTML page where text loaded from a database will appear. It will have URLs that need to be clickable. Additionally, the user must be able to edit this text (it doesn't need to be saved to the database or anything, just edited for now).
So far, I have a contenteditable div inside a table cell:

`<td>
<div contentEditable="true">
<c:out "whatever" escapeXML="false"/> </div></td>`

There is also a javascript method that parses any http:// or www. words into links: after testing, it works. This almost works; the text is loaded, the field is editable, and the links get bolded, turned blue, et cetera, BUT when I hover my mouse over the links they are unclickable. Does anyone know what the issue is and if there is an easy workaround to achieve what I need??

Comment: what is the code being generated by the javascript? How does the js add the content? More information is needed.

Comment: As good solution is proposed for this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2459180/476786

Comment: The click event would likely be used for text editing, i.e.: selection, cursor position. You might want to use different approach to open the given URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059211/how-to-make-clickable-anchor-in-contenteditable-div